# Add text to Facebook message box to dialog opened via share button

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

I'm trying to add a message to the facebook using share button, I successfully added  thumbnail and description but don't know the tag to add text to the message box. Is this possible?

I'm using ASP.NET frame 3.5 
[image: Screenshot of sharing dialog]

here is my code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share\" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta name="description" content="<%=GetText() %>" />
    <link rel="image_src" href="http://www.murrayhilltech.com/images/LogoColorNoText.jpg" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <a name="fb_share" type="button" share_url="<%=GetURL() %>">Facebook</a>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, this isn't possible using `Share Button` Social Widget.

Even in `Feed Dialog` `message` is ignored now, cite from [`Feed Dialog` documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) about this field:

> This field will be ignored on July 12, 2011 The message to prefill the text field that the user will type in. To be compliant with Facebook Platform Policies, your application may only set this field if the user manually generated the content earlier in the workflow. Most applications should not set this.

You can only fill `message` field via [`FB.api`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) (JS-SDK) or via [Graph API publishing](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts) if user granted `publish_stream` permission for your application.